# iOS concurrency: NSOperationQueue and ARC issue

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, concurrency, automatic-ref-counting, nsoperationqueue

I am currently implementing a multithreaded application and I encounter a strange race condition (leading to an ARC problem: **error for object 0x7f8bcbd6a1c0: pointer being freed was not allocated**).

The app creates multiple NSOperations, each one is downloading and processing information. As in every one of these NSOperations an error may occur (e.g., the web service is not available), I want to propagate the error up so I can handle it. However, I seem to encounter a race condition and the operations try to access invalid memory.

A minimalistic example which shows the memory access problem is the following one:

```
- (void) createError: (NSError**) err {
    *err = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"Test" code:12345 userInfo:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    __block NSError *globalError = nil;

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    NSOperation *op = nil;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        op = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
            NSError *err = nil;
            [self createError:&err];

            // This loop increases the chance to get the race condition
            for (int j=0; j<10000;j++) {
                @synchronized(globalError) {
                      globalError = err;
                }
            }
        }];
        [queue addOperation:op];
    }

    [queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];

    if (globalError) {
        NSLog(@"An error occured in at least one of the operations");
    }
}
```

Whenever I run this program, I get an exception. Mostly it is **error for object 0x7fc0b860e860: pointer being freed was not allocated**, however, sometimes I also got an EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT) break in the debugger.

I have added the for-Loop over 10000 iterations only to increase the chance that the race condition occurs. If I leave it, the error only occurs in rare occasions (but still has to be fixed, obviously I am doing something wrong here).

Comment: I think I found it. I synchronised on nil, which effectively does not perform any synchronisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@synchronized` directive uses the object you pass to control the synchronization, so, as you note, you're trying to synchronize on `nil`. And even if it wasn't `nil`, the object referenced by the `@synchronized` directive is a different object every time, largely defeating the attempt to synchronize.

The easiest change is to use `@synchronized(self)`, instead. Or, create a `NSLock` object and then `lock` and `unlock` it when you access `globalError`. Or, if this was a high demand situation, use GCD queue (either serial queue or reader-writer pattern).